# Component oriented programming for rich RPG world

Tags: architecture, component-based, oop

I've asked this question on several forums but didn't get the proper answer yet.

So, in my opinion, it is a really theoritical and deep, but I really can't deal with it by myself.

**What is my goal?**

I want to create a TES-inspired (The Elder Scrolls series) RPG with a really behaviour-complex world, when as a player you can, for example, not only play on *guitar* as a *Musical Instrument*, but use it as a *Weapon* or, what is perhaps more unobvious, *throw it* right to the *furnace* to get some heat in a cold winter night.

**What did I get so far?**

I started with upper-level ontology, because such world must have really deep complex hierarchies. There were an `Entity`, then `MaterialEntity` (with time and space extensions) and `AbstractEntity` (`Notions`, `Relationships` and so on). `MaterialEntity` was divided to `Event`, `PhysicalObject` (with mass and temperature). The last ones consisted of `Creatures`, `Things`, `Substances` (like water which is uncountable in the same sense as apples) and so on.

Then there was a *big* problem with tree-like inheritance: in the previous example a guitar was a `MusicalInstrument`, `Weapon` and `Fuel` at one time, furthermore there are a lot of another ways to *interpret* the thing and interact with it.

I decided that OOP with it's 2D Types (2D because every entity can be placed in a simple table with rows and columns) paradigm just not fit well in such complex case (like Newton's force formula for Mercury) and I need something better.

**What did I tried?**

1. **Interfaces**. *Pros*: Simple and obvious. *Cons*: A lot of code duplications and hard *SRP*-violation. Just imagine how many `IOpeneable` things you will have in code (door, bottle, box, chest, window and so on).
2. **Strategy Design Pattern**. *Pros*: More reusability that interfaces. *Cons*: old remain with *DI* handling added.
3. **Components or Entity Systems**. Pros: A lot of reusability, no duplication at all. Seems like this is a good choice for me, but...

**The cons of COP (or just my misunderstanding)**

I think that *COP* seems great for my task (and for other games) because it makes all the static compile-time coupling more runtime and dynamic, but it sacrifies **a lot** for it: the intelligibility of code, because now you see

```
entity.GetComponent<Openeable>.Open()
```

or

```
entity.GetComponent<Inventory>.AddItem( anotherEntity.GetComponent<Item>() )
```

instead of

```
box.Open();
```

or

```
inventory.AddItem( weapon );
```

As a developer I want my code to reflect the domain as much as possible, so the whole `Component-Entity` paradigm looks strange because there are nothing like *components* or *systems* in real (or game) world. In another words: I want more that just shift compile-time to run-time as COP does sacrificing the clarity of code.

Sorry for such long introduction, I just wanted to clarify the problem as much as possible.

**The main question**

Are there modern extensions of `COP` so far or should I just use another paradigm for my problem?

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: "because there are nothing like components or systems in real (or game) world" -- the computer doesn't give a hoot about your taxonomical idea of how real life is organized. Code is behavior that operates on data; do _not_ try to think about code like it's a set of real-world objects and nouns. Proper and correct OOP (which is entirely orthogonal to the rigid hierarchical type systems you're fighting, btw) is about organizing behavior and data, not about making pretty English-like interfaces.

Comment: Maybe I'll look dumb by asking this, but what do you mean by "extensions of COP"?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch thanks for the opinion. You're absolutely right, but this is an ambigious point of view. Actually I think that code should reflect the domain you work with, as much as possible, so this is not just about _English-like_ interfaces, but a correct set of notions, from which you will implement your domain in code. `COP` is a good thing to go, but maybe there are modern alternatives of it... Maybe I just need some time to realize obvious things.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt by "extensions of COP" mean something like modern framework, that takes idea of `COP` and turns it into something new: maybe more structured and world-related.

Comment: @bcrist hey, thanks a lot for this article. It looks like good way to go from that point to get a deep understanding.

Comment: @AshkarielEter: a matter of opinion, agreed. :) OOP patterns limit your potential efficiency and open you up to more error-prone code (null dereference bugs are more common working with objects than in data-oriented approach, in my experience). you can get the best of both worlds by avoiding excessive OOP in your low-level code and then using OOP-like interfaces in your domain-specific scripting language, since your script language can effectively translate a nice `thing.open()` into the low-level `if thing then openable = thing.get<open>() : if openable then openable.open() else raise error`.

Answer (score 6):

Taking the example of the guitar:

> (...) a player you can, for example, not only play on guitar as a Musical Instrument, but use it as a Weapon or, what is perhaps more unobvious, throw it right to the furnace to get some heat in a cold winter night.

First off, move away from using object inheritance to model this. Although, I want to note that using OOP is not wrong, but this kind of OOD (Object Oriented Design) doesn't yield well to what you want.

You should prefer [Composition over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). If you can model `The Guitar has Musical Behaviour` instead of `The Guitar is a Musical Instrument` then do that.

---

Next up, you need to be able to plug in those behaviours. The reason is because you will not be able to develop systems for playing musical instruments, armed combat and item forge all at once. In fact, you don't want bugs of one of those systems to ruin the others... what you need is to ["be open for extension, but closed for modification"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

So, you need a way to extend composition.

This rasoning leads you stright to this option:

> *Components or Entity Systems*. Pros: A lot of reusability, no duplication at all. Seems like this is a good choice for me (...)

---

> but...
>
> (...)
>
> the whole Component-Entity paradigm looks strange because there are nothing like components or systems in real (or game) world

But there are! At least in the game world there would be. For example, you could create a game where there is no way to craft items, instead you need to get them from drops or buy them from NPCs... and then at a later date you can add a *forge system*... as part of this update you would add "meterial attributes" to the objects (or reuse some existing ones) to become crafting materials. So you see, the game world has systems.

Notice I say that the *forge system* is not a component of the objects. Instead I say that the object has "material attributes". This is because you don't need to add extra behaviour to the objects, just the relevant attributes that the new systems will manipulate or interact with.

---

About the "the intelligibility" and <strike>the "pretentiousness of code" (Is that measurable?)</strike>... you have options:

**1. Combine interfaces with components**

For example if you write a `IHasInventory` interface... instead of writing:

```
entity.GetComponent<Inventory>.AddItem( anotherEntity.GetComponent<Item>() )
```

You could write:

```
entity.Inventory.AddItem(anotherEntity);
```

Given that the variable `entity` is of type `IHasInventory` and `Inventory` is a property of that interface.

Of course, this approach means that you will not be adding components dynamically (unless this is a dynamic language). But, do you really need to add components in runtime?

Also, you will not be writing the logic for inventory a lot of times, because there would be a single `Inventory` class. So, no SRP concerns here.

**2. Use a more dynamic language**: For instance, with a dynamic type, in the line:

```
entity.Inventory.AddItem(anotherEntity);
```

Inventory could have been added in runtime:

```
entity.Inventory = new Inventory();
```

even if `Inventory` is not a property of `entity`. For example in JavaScript you can add attributes to an already created object.

**3. Embrace it**: You can be pretentious, I give you my blessing.

---

**Addendum: On dealing with damage**

> It looks more natural to see sentence "I attacked him" instead of "I get my weapon component to deal with it's armor component" or "The system check my input and calculated attack damage on guy"

It wouldn't be the "weapon component" and the "armor component". The first reasons being that the the target needs to be able to take damage, not just it's armor. The second reason...

You have a character that have weapons that have attributes. Usually some weapon will be equiped and the character attacks with that. You may also want to consider attacking without weapon. So you can think of the attack as being modified by the equiped weapon.

So, I suggest to think about it in terms of "cause damage" instead of attack. This will ease to implement things like buff/debuff mechanics or status effects that do damage over time (eg: poison).

In terms of "cause damage" you want to say something along the lines of "my character causes damage to the enemy"

```
myCharacter.Damage(enemy);
```

But that sounds like you need to implement `damage` multiple times... which is what leads you to write something like this:

```
myCharacter.Combat.Damage(enemy.Combat);
```

Or perhaps

```
myCharacter.Combat.Damage(enemy);
```

If you consider that there could be effects on various components. In my opinion that looks good enough... yet, what about wrapping that? You don't need to write like that each time, instead:

```
Combat.Damage(myCharacter, enemy);
```

Where `Combat` is a class that handles attacks, so you only would worry to populate in the entities the attributes you need to compute the damage.

About damage over time and other damage sources, you could consider the `Combat.Damage` method to be adding a damage source & damage target pair... then have a `Combat.Update` compute the actual damage and have it run as part of the game loop / tick / wolrd update method... this way `Combat.Update` will be able to compute damage over time, remove damage sources once they are done, or even add new ones for damage status.

**Addendum: "openable"**

There is no need to implement it as anything more than `IOpenable` interface with a `IsOpen` property. To open you could then write:

```
entity.IsOpen = true;
```

Or

```
entity.SetOpen(true); // for those languages >.>
```

So, this can be implemented just as attributes. Of course, you may choose to have `Open` and `Close` methods... although there is no need to.

Besides. You shouldn't implement an "Openable" as a class, because bein "Open" means something different for doors, chests, etc... So, I'm saying that "Inventory" class makes sense, but "Openable" class does not. In fact, I would question whatever or not having an abstraction for "openable" makes sense... but that depends on the game.

---

I want to note that I'm saying to use interfaces to access the components, intead of whatever component library you are using (with which you are clearly not happy about the syntax you need to use).

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

I appreciate all of your practical advices, and I've already tried to design the world with every of it. 

Sadly, the _COP_ thing is just sometimes nonobvious, and as I think right now it is because of it's irreal nature. It looks more natural to see sentence "_I attacked him_" instead of "_I get my weapon component to deal with it's armor component_" or "_The system check my input and calculated attack damage on guy_". Maybe there is some more clear version with such dynamic coupling.

Comment: I've also tried to develop a `COP`-based system with different semantics. For example, if you have an `entity` and you want to open it as every openeable object such as door, box, chest or whatever, you will do something like that `entity.As<IOpeneable>.Open()`, so this allows you to go away from nonobvious semantics and encapsulate the components thing. To add a component you'll use `entity.BelongsToClass<IOpeneable>()`.
But then what is a state or property of entity and what is behaviour? So many questions...

Comment: @AshkarielEter expanded answer to address your comments. Edit: I don't know what language and library you are using, and I don't really know what you plan to model... you may want to consider to ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea of components is to break the code out into thier own domains. The side effect of doing that is you end up with nice small totally contained components.

I look at components as individual libraries. They should know nothing about the outside world. Because of this interfaces are a bad way to go in my view. Interfaces create coupling between components and said interface. Why would you need that? Instead components should have functions that work on thier internal state and events to tell the outside world what's going on inside the component. Those become your input and output for the component and it makes them 100% decoupled from everything so they can just do thier one specific domain and do it well. This also helps with performance because you can test each domain independently to see how it performs and make changes to just that component.

The question then becomes how do the components within a given game object communicate? They do so by having a unique script per unique game object. I call this the same name as the game object and append CommHub to it. This is the communication hub for all those components that make up this game object. In here is where you hook up all the components events to other components functions. You now have a central place to easily see how that game object works at a glance. This high level view of a game object is so valuable! The way ppl normally do things in Unity by accessing components from within components doesn't show you in one place how the game object works. It's messy, don't do that.

The question then becomes how game objects interact with other game objects and again while keeping them unaware of each other and thier components. This is where systems come in. Each interaction that has to happen gets a singleton systems class. This is the communication bridge between game objects components talking to each other. A system functions and a matching events. Again your game object comm hub script is where you hook components to systems. One game object component will raise and event which will call a system function. That system function in turn raises its matching event, which a different game object component in its comm hub subscribed to so it's function gets called.

This gives you two game objects who are oblivious of each other and isolated a way to communicate when an interaction needs to happen. Not to mention it makes the comm hub script the command central for all communication for each game object which is invaluable to see all in one place.

For ideas:

PlayerInput component fires events like onMoveForwardHit, onJumpHit. The Controller component has functions like MoveForward, Jump, Stop. It has events like onLanded. The Sound component has functions like PlayFootsteps, PlayLand.

Inside your PlayerCommHub script you hook all these events to functions. Next thing you know when you press the 'w' key your guy moves forward and is making walking sounds!

Extend this idea to everything in your game and you'll have a very decoupled, easy to maintain and change, and unit testable codebase!

Also don't use SendMessage because again it puts how your object works from a high level inside each component. Do you want to go through 20 source files flipping back and forth trying to follow flow of messages or do you want to see all component interactions in one source file (comm hub). This file as no is statement or loops. It simply has events being tied to functions. So easy to visualize what that game object is doing and how it interacts with other game objects and components.

Comment: Good high level overview. A bit too advanced for the OP at the time I believe though.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is genius or just one take at Unity project architectures. Need more comments.

Comment: @OneManMonkeySquad It's just a different kind of way to organize a project really. I think most people agree that decoupling is a good idea. This helps take it to another level and gives you 1 place to see it all. I recently did this same idea with a FSM in unity. With each state being it's own class I needed ways to share data between states.I didn't want a global dumping ground so the states have delegates in them to get the data it needs.The CommHub where I created all states then hooks up the events between states.So StateC calls delegate to get data StateA has and each state is decoupled.